# How do I color every second row in a table while using Shiny?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I have written a function in my global.R-script, that takes a dataframe and some parameters and returns a datatable to be viewed in my Shiny app. The function works until I try to make every other row in the datatable have the background color '#00ff00' and the other rows have the background color '#0000ff'.

I have tried writing a css-file with the following code in it

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #00ff00;}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #0000ff;}
```

but that did not affect the colors, probably because Shiny has some default css or javascript code that has priority. My css-file still controls the background color for the Shiny app and the colors in the head of the table, so it does work.

My best attempt so far is the following code:

```
  scroll_y <- min(nrow(df)*30+150,650)
  
  my.rows <- 1:nrow(df)
  my.colors <- ifelse(my.rows %% 2 == 0, '#00ff00', '#0000ff')

  datanames <- names(df)
  df$row <- my.rows
  df <- df[c("row", datanames)]
  
  t <- DT::datatable(
    df,
    rownames = FALSE,
    # class = "cell-border," 
    # class = "table table-hover", 
    class = "table-hover", 
    colnames = col_names,
    options = list(
      columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 1:(ncol(df) - 1))),
      paging=FALSE,
      searching=FALSE,
      filtering=FALSE,
      ordering=FALSE,
      scrollY=scroll_y,
      dom = 't',
      bSort=FALSE,
      scrollCollapse=FALSE #,
      # rowCallback = DT::JS(
      #   "function(row, data) {",
      #   "  if (data[0] % 2 === 1) {",
      #   "    $(row).css('background-color', '#0000FF');",
      #   "  }else if(data[0] % 2 === 0) {",
      #   "    $(row).css('background-color', '#FF0000');",
      #   "  }",
      #   "}"
      # )
    ),
    escape = TRUE,
    selection = "none",
    fillContainer = TRUE#,
  ) %>% 
    DT::formatStyle(
      columns = 'row',
      target = 'row',
      backgroundColor = DT::styleEqual(my.rows, my.colors)
    ) #%>%
    # DT::removeColumn(0)
    # DT::formatStyle(
    #   0,
    #   backgroundColor = DT::styleEqual(c(0,1), c("#f0f0f0", "#ffffff")),
    #   rowIdx = "Mod(row.index, 2)"
    # )
```

I have kept code that was commented out for you to see my other attempts at solving this issue.

I want the code above to display tables with the columns in the dataframe "df", as it looks before I add the column "row", but I cannot remove that column i seems. `DT::removeColumn(0)` was suggested to me, but that function seems to not exist. I also tried to remove the column "row" by writing `t <- t[,"row":=NULL]`
or `t <- t[, "row", with = FALSE]`, but I got an error saying "`:=` can only be used within dynamic dots.".

I have commented out some javascript code that works outside of Shiny, but not in my Shiny app.

If there is a solution that uses a vector that I can calculate my self and giving me full control of the colors of each row, then that would be preferred, since I haven't really worked with javascript or css before and since I might want the last row for example to have another color than the rest of the table rows. Solutions that uses my css-file or that uses javascript are of course still of interest, especially since I can share my css-file with my colleagues easily.

Comment: assuming you custom CSS loads OK: you could try to override competing CSS with "!important", e.g.: `tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #00ff00 !important;}`

Comment: Have you used your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly who/where is setting the CSS for those elements?